# How can I set different language in Google Maps iframe embedded?

Tags: google-maps, iframe

I embed Google Maps on my page using this iframe code:

`<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2969.0008243929688!2d12.508442200000003!3d41.914341!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x132f6172a14507ef%3A0xc7f898288c2080d1!2sCorso+Trieste%2C+1%2C+00198+Roma!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1430587054219" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>`

and it works well but map indication are shown in language in which the browser is set (e.g. if the language browser is set to Italian then map indication are shown in Italian).

How can I force arbitrarily map language (e.g. German)?

I tried to add `&language=de` parameter but it doesn't work

`<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d2969.0008243929688!2d12.508442200000003!3d41.914341!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x132f6172a14507ef%3A0xc7f898288c2080d1!2sCorso+Trieste%2C+1%2C+00198+Roma!5e0!3m2!1sit!2sit!4v1430587054219&language=de" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>`

Answer (score 0):

Had a play around with it, but I couldn't get it to work either. Looks like its a bug on Google's side.

An alternative work around that I saw working is to use the **Google Maps JS API**, which is a bit more work but the `language` parameter seems to work.

There is an example here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-language

Comment: Thank you. It works but now info box (http://s5.postimg.org/d4pwnwkhj/box.png) isn't shown and there's no mark on the place. Do you know also how to add it?